# Sequence of functions that converges strongly in $L^3$, weakly in $L^2$ and not strongly in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

How can I construct a sequence of functions $f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f_n \overset{L^3}{\to} 0 \\ f_n \overset{w-L^2}{\to} 0 \\ f_n \overset{L^2}{\not\to} 0 $$ I know without the convergence in $L^3$ part you want to use something like an orthonormal basis...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take disjoint intervals $I_1,I_2,\ldots$ with lengths $l_1, l_2, \ldots$ such that $\lim_n l_n=\infty$.

Let $f_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{l_n}}1_{I_n}$. Because the intervals are pairwise disjoint, this is an orthonormal family in $L_2$, and is therefore weakly converging to $0$ in $L_2$. Since the sequence is weakly convergent to $0$ in $L_2$, if it were strongly convergent to something in $L_2$, that something would have to be $0$. But $$\|f_n\|_2=1$$ for all $n$, so the sequence $f_n$ cannot converge strongly in $L_2$.  Last, $$\|f_n\|_3 =l_n^{-1/6}\to 0,$$ so $f_n$ converges strongly to $0$ in $L_3$.